# SAP Netweaver. C++ Error:The memory cannot be read

Tags: c++, netweaver

For my project, I need to test if the router string connects with SAP server successfully using SAP Netweaver 7.0. I have created a Console application in Visual studio 2017. I have given the connection parameters. But the application ends with an error: The memory cannot be read

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "include/sapnwrfc.h"


void errorHandling(RFC_RC rc,  RFC_ERROR_INFO*errorInfo, RFC_CONNECTION_HANDLE connection) {

    printfU(cU("%s:  %s\n"), errorInfo->key, errorInfo->message);
    /* It's better to close the TCP/IP connection cleanly, than tojust let the backend get a "Connection reset by peer" error...*/
    if (connection != NULL)  RfcCloseConnection(connection, errorInfo);
    exit(1);
}


int mainU(int argc, SAP_UC** argv)
{
    RFC_RC  rc = RFC_OK;   
    RFC_CONNECTION_PARAMETER  loginParams[6];  
    RFC_ERROR_INFO  errorInfo;   
    RFC_CONNECTION_HANDLE  connection;

    //  -----------------------------------------------
    //  OPEN CONNECTION
    //  -----------------------------------------------
    //  Create logon parameter list
    loginParams[0].name = cU("gwhost");
    loginParams[0].value = cU("80.**.***.**");
    loginParams[1].name = cU("sysnr");
    loginParams[1].value = cU("00");
    loginParams[2].name = cU("client");
    loginParams[2].value = cU("800");
    loginParams[3].name = cU("user");
    loginParams[3].value = cU("jsar12");
    loginParams[4].name = cU("lang");
    loginParams[4].value = cU("EN");
    loginParams[5].name = cU("****");
    loginParams[5].value = cU("Abc");

    //  Open connection
    connection = RfcOpenConnection(loginParams, 6, &errorInfo);
    if (connection == NULL) errorHandling(rc, &errorInfo, NULL);

    return 0;
}
```

Expected Result: Connection to the SAP Router

Answer (score 0):

The solution for the above problem was in the settings of the Visual Studio. After a lot of searching and trying out a few tricks I have found the solution in the following link:
https://answers.sap.com/questions/12367200/netweaver-rfc-connector-error-logon.html

Summary:

```
On Linux and Windows, certain minimum releases of the C runtime are required to execute the programs. See SAP Notes 1021236 (for Linux) and 684106 (for Windows). The compiler and linker options needed to compile programs using the SAP NetWeaver RFC SDK are listed in SAP Note 1056696.

In addition, for Windows users using Microsoft Visual Studio, this is a description of how to set the Visual Studio project properties:

General section: Make sure the CharacterSet field is set to “Use Unicode Character Set.”

Debugging section: Under Environment, add something like Path=%Path%;nwrfcsdk\lib.

C/C++ section:

General: Add the nwrfcsdk\include directory under Additional Include Directories.

Preprocessor: Add the two preprocessor definitions SAPonNT and SAPwithUNICODE.

Code Generation: Choose “Multi-threaded DLL (/MD)” as the Runtime Library; selecting “Multi-threaded Debug DLL (/MDd)” may lead to strange problems.

Linker section:

General: Add the nwrfcsdk\lib directory under Additional Library Directories.

Input: Under Additional Dependencies, add libsapucum.lib, sapnwrfc.lib, and sapdecfICUlib.lib
```